# If $f$ is injective then $ann\left(N\right)\subseteq ann\left(M\right)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $f$ be $R$-homorphism from $R$-module $M$ to $R$-module $N$. Prove
>   that if $f$ is injective then $ann\left(N\right)\subseteq ann\left(M\right)$.

$ann\left(N\right)=\left\{ r\in R:rx=0\forall x\in N\right\}$

Let $y\in ann\left(N\right)$
 , we have $yx=0\forall x\in N$
 . Since $y=f\left(z\right)$
  with $z\in M$
  and $\forall x\in N\exists t\in M:t=f\left(x\right)$
 . Hence $f\left(zt\right)=f\left(z\right)f\left(t\right)=yx=0\Longrightarrow zt=0$

What should I do then?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? Have you considered what it means for an $R$-homomorphism to be injective? How about the definition of an annihilator?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What does it mean to be in the annihilator? Write this down and use the fact that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

You have that

$$M\cong f(M)\le N$$

and thus your work basically reduces (though it is *not* the same exactly!) to show that

$$M\le N\implies \text{ann}\,(N)\le\text{ann}\,(M)$$

which seems to be fairly simple.

Comment: +$1$ good hint :)

Comment: ...and yet someone thought it deserves a downvote. Oh, well...:)